# How to use in output a single utf-8 char with any other symbol?

Tags: c, utf-8, char, output

I wanted to print a single char in a new line, but get '?' in terminal with non-ASCII symbols. How can I avoid this?
I checked information in the internet, but didn't succeed. Thanks in advance!

```
char buff[255] = "хай, man";
int slen1 = strlen(buff);
printf("%s\n", buff);
for (int i=0; i < slen1; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", buff[i]);
}
```

It happens if I use *%c* with any other symbol.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWbeN.png)

Comment: https://quick-adviser.com/what-is-the-difference-between-wchar-and-char/

Comment: What do you mean with "char"? There is the type `char`, which is 1 byte, there are unicode code points, which in UTF8 can have between 1-4 byte (or `char` assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`), and there are unicode characters which can consist of 1 or more code points (there are combining code points). There is `wchar_t` which depends on your system (Can by same as `char`, can be a 16 or 32 bit integer to store a single unicode code point, ....).

Comment: In your case, `"%c\n"` will output a single byte (a C `char`) of the input followed by linefeed. UTF8 may use more than a single byte for a code point. You need to store the character in a bigger type, such as `unsigned`, `wchar_t`, `uint32_t`or something else. and combine the content of multiple `char`s depending on how many bytes belong to a single code point.

Comment: On which system are you? On Linux you could use `mbstowcs()` to convert the string to `wchar_t *` and use it to print one code point after the other. On Windows you can't use `wchar_t` since there `wchar_t` is only 16 bit and some code points need more than that (Windows uses UTF16).

Comment: What is the reason you use `int` for `slen1`? `strlen()` returns `size_t`. And why do you use a signed integer?

Comment: Do not put links to images. If the image is important, just include the image (so that image and answer are available also in future). But if you can: just copy the text in such image). Do no expect programmers will follow random links from unknown people.

Comment: In any case: your task may be difficult. You can split strings **before** characters < 128 or >= 192), so you have an entire codepoint. But there are combining characters/codepoints. And in such case you may need to keep many codepoint together. You need an entire unicode database. And there is Korean. And emoji with variations, flags, And there are other problems (you may find all in UAX #29: Unicode Text Segmentation.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know the string is UTF-8 encoded, we could process the string with custom code.
Note this is error prone.  Below also lacks error checking.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char buff[255] = u8"хай, man";
  printf("buff[] <%s>\n", buff);
  size_t len = strlen(buff);
  printf("string length %zu\n", len);
  for (size_t i = 0; i<=len; i++) {
    printf("%zu %02X %c\n", i, 0xFFu & (unsigned) buff[i],
        isprint((unsigned char) buff[i]) ? buff[i] :  '?' );
  }
  puts("");

  for (size_t i = 0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("%zu ", i);
    char ch = buff[i];
    // If ASCII character ....
    if ((ch & 0x80) == 0) {  
      printf("%c\n", ch);
    } else {
      // Process UTF-8
      char b[5] = { ch };
      size_t j;
      for (j = 1; (j < 4) && ((buff[i+j] & 0xC0) == 0x80); j++) {
        b[j] = buff[i+j];
      }
      b[j] = 0;
      printf("%s\n", b);  // Print 1 UTF-8 character.
      i += j - 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
buff[] <хай, man>
string length 11
0 D1 ?
1 85 ?
2 D0 ?
3 B0 ?
4 D0 ?
5 B9 ?
6 2C ,
7 20  
8 6D m
9 61 a
10 6E n
11 00 ?

0 х
2 а
4 й
6 ,
7  
8 m
9 a
10 n
```

Comment: Thank you! It's works great and I figured out a little how to work with unicode with a help of you!